# Suggestion for keeping graph in memory for api access

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-ec2

I have built a graph on my local machine, and I want to provide access to it through an API. I would like to have this on a server.

My question is, how do I save the graph so that each time it is queried, it doesn't have to parse the data, then build, then traverse and answer (every single time it is queried). I would like to keep it "alive" so that it can be queried.

Two ways I was thinking:

1. Load my java program on EC2 and have it build the graph and leave it running, just listening for queries. When a query comes, it will access the graph, return answer. (I think this will be expensive)
2. Save graph as a blob in mysql, then have a query that gets that graph, searches and then returns the result.

3... Any better ways??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a graph based datastore such as Neo4j or Orient DB...... They are a better fit for your purpose.